# The userPassword is invalid after RemoveField when itextSharp5.5.10 is used

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Here is a PDF file that requires a password to open, and I added an electronic signature to it. A password is still required to open the file after this. But after I use `AcroFields.RemoveField` to remove the electronic signature, a password is no longer required to open the file. Is this normal? How can I keep the password when opening the PDF file?

test pdf
https://github.com/IYinxf/PDFs/blob/master/Encrypted.pdf

password is 11111111

code

```
pdfReader = new PdfReader(strTempPath, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword));
if (!pdfReader.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions)
{
    return ERR_PERMISSION_DENIED;
}

AcroFields af = pdfReader.AcroFields;
bool rv = af.RemoveField(fieldName);
```

Comment: You might want to share enough code and an example PDF to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, I added the test PDF and code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code responsible for keeping encryption information

```
if (reader.IsEncrypted() && (append || PdfReader.unethicalreading)) {
    crypto = new PdfEncryption(reader.Decrypt);
}
```

*(`PdfStamperImp` constructor)*

this only happens if you are stamping in append mode or if the `unethicalreading` flag is set.

When testing your code in append mode, it turns out that the field is not removed. This is caused by the `AcroFields` field removal code not properly marking the correct updated objects in your PDF as *used*. When you do the marking manually, it works fine:

```
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(file, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword)))
using (FileStream output = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output, '\0', true))
{
    AcroFields af = pdfReader.AcroFields;
    bool rv = af.RemoveField(fieldName);
    pdfStamper.MarkUsed(pdfReader.Catalog);
    for (int pageNo = 1; pageNo <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageNo++)
    {
        pdfStamper.MarkUsed(pdfReader.GetPageN(pageNo));
    }
}
```

Testing with the `unethicalreading` flag set to `true` works out-of-the-box:

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(file, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strPassword)))
using (FileStream output = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, output))
{
    AcroFields af = pdfReader.AcroFields;
    bool rv = af.RemoveField(fieldName);
}
```